# How to get META keywords content with VBA from source code in an EXCEL file

Tags: html, excel, keyword, meta-tags, vba

I have to download the source code of a several hundred websites to an Excel file (for example to cells(1, 1) in Worksheets 1) and then extract the content of of the META tag keywords in let's say cells(1, 2).

For downloading I use the following code in VBA:

```
Dim htm As Object
Set htm = CreateObject("HTMLfile")
URL = "https://www.insolvenzbekanntmachungen.de/cgi-bin/bl_aufruf.pl?PHPSESSID=8ecbeb942c887974468b9010531fc7ab&datei=gerichte/nw/agkoeln/16/0071_IN00181_16/2016_06_10__11_53_26_Anordnung_Sicherungsmassnahmen.htm"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    Cells(1, 1) = .responseText
End With
```

I've found the following code on this website but, unfortunately, I'm unable to adapt it to solve my problem:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim str As String
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim webpage As New HTMLDocument
Dim item As HTMLHtmlElement

Set wk = Worksheets(1)
str = "https://www.insolvenzbekanntmachungen.de/cgi-bin/bl_aufruf.pl?PHPSESSID=8ecbeb942c887974468b9010531fc7ab&datei=gerichte/nw/agkoeln/16/0071_IN00181_16/2016_06_10__11_53_26_Anordnung_Sicherungsmassnahmen.htm"
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate str

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


'Find the proper meta element --------------
Const META_TAG As String = "META"
Const META_NAME As String = "keywords"
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim metaElements As Object
Dim element As Object
Dim kwd As String


Set Doc = ie.Document
Set metaElements = Doc.all.tags(META_TAG)

For Each element In metaElements
    If element.Name = META_NAME Then
        kwd = element.Content
    End If
Next

MsgBox kwd
```

End Sub

I think I have to modify this line, but don't know how:

```
Set Doc = ie.Document
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Why do you "think I have to modify this line"? What messages do you get back if you move your msgbox inside your loop after "kwd="

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor english. I'm afraid I didn't express myself correctly. The code that I've posted and which I found on this site works perfect. Umfortunately, I do not want to a website and extract the META tags from the website itself but from the source code of the website which I have copied to cells(1, 1) in an Excel worksheet. That's why I thought that I have to change the code line. I don't want to refer to ie.document but to cells(1, 1).

Answer (score 0):

Embed a WebrowserControl into a Excel Spreadsheet or userform 
[How to add a Webrowser to Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1q2W-mkzFI)

Set up references to the HTML Object Library
[How to add VBA References – Internet Controls, HTML Object Library](http://automatetheweb.net/how-to-add-vba-references-internet-controls-html-object-library/)

Grab Greg Truby's code from this post [Webbroswer Control](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/174102-webbrowser-control.html)

You'll have access the Document Object Model (DOM).  This will expose most of the HTMLElements properties and event's

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents htmDocument As HTMLDocument
Private WithEvents MyButton As HTMLButtonElement

Private Function MyButton_onclick() As Boolean
    MsgBox "Sombody Click MyButton on WebBrowser1"
End Function

Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateComplete2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Dim aTags As Hyperlinks

    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set MyButton = htmDocument.getElementById("MyButtonID")
    Set htmDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
    Set aTags = htmDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")
End Sub
```

Google Web Api, HTA, (MDN){https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API} and if you get stuck try to refactor Javascript code to vbscript.  It's