# Trying to webscrape HTML page, using XMLHTMLRequest method from within Excel VBA, but gets Run-time error 438

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, runtime-error

Trying to mimick, exactly whats described here:
[WebScraping only specific sections of a webpage in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239160/webscraping-only-specific-sections-of-a-webpage-in-vba)

However, my code get an alright XMLHTTPRequest (Status=200) populated object, with a fine `.responseText` (with HTML), but then it breaks in this assignment (see code near bottom):

```
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
```

with the dreaded

> **Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method**

from within Excel 2019 (ie 365) VBA.

I have tried to tweak it, but cannot come across this issue. I want to traverse some of the HTML element types, once it works.

The only forum answers, to this problem deals with IE, but I am beyond Internet Explorer ;-)

Any clues, anyone?

```
Sub GetMetaData()
' Original idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763179/how-to-get-meta-keywords-content-with-vba-from-source-code-in-an-excel-file
' Adapted by PR to work in general i.e. not being Browser specific in any way
' 2022-09-29
Dim webrequest      As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim responses       As Object
Dim HTMLDoc         As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLElement     As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim url As String: url = "https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata"
Dim wk As Worksheet

Const META_TAG As String = "META"
Const META_NAME As String = "keywords"
Dim Doc As Object                      ' As work area, holding HTML
Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")     ' to fake ...
Dim metaElements As Object
Dim element As Object
Dim kwd As String
Dim err As Integer
Dim myarray As Variant: ReDim myarray(0 To 20, 0 To 5000)

Set wk = Worksheets(6)    ' Hopefully a free worksheet

' Find the HTML document near the URL
With webrequest
            .Open "GET", url, True                                       ' Have to use Asynchronously (True), or I get error setting ResponseType !
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html, */*"           ' Replaced header, to be more specific
            '.responseType = "document"                       ' We cannot operate on any other content than HTML. Tryin, gives Runtime error 438
            ' Added below header, to ensure its compatible.
            .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            Debug.Print "Request Status:", .Status, .statusText   ' To see result of XMLHTTP60 request
            HTMLDoc.Body.innnerHTML = .responseText       ' CODE line giving error    ' Pick up the HTML
            Set info = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(META_TAG)
            Debug.Print "We now have Document META collection (nodelist): ", info
            
            On Error Resume Next ' getting an error, just ignoring for now
End with
```

Comment: Please see what a [mcve] is and provide one. With only one line of code that you show it is impossible to say what exatcly the cause of the issue is.

Comment: What is it you wish to scrape from that webpage?

Comment: Basically, the Updated datefield (in META tag).
But originally, I wanted to grab the table of dates shown last, of RHEL versions and their End of Life milestones. This seems difficult due to this table is scripted from within a script instead of plain html table.